# Python: print statements not finding values in 2nd half, printing method bound?

Tags: python, class, object

Im trying to create a rectangle object that takes height and width and calculates perimeter and area. It seems that the first rectangle is able to calculate the area and perimeter, but the 2nd rectangle just breaks by saying it cannot find height or width, or any of the other values that i need returned. Also, when the first rectangle is printed, it prints a "method bound" thing instead of the actual values of the functions:

```
   class Rectangle:
def __init__(self,height=2, width=2):
    self.height = (height)
    self.width = (width)



def setHeight(height):
    if type(height)!=int:
        height = 2
    else:
        height = height
def setWidth(width):
    if type(width)!=int:
        width = 2
    else:
        width = width

def getHeight():
    return height
def getWidth():
    return width


def perimeter(self):
    perimeter = ((2*height)+(2*width))
    return perimeter


def area(self):
    area = (height * width)
    return area

def getStats(self):
    print("Width: {}".format(width))
    print("Height: {}".format(height))
    print("Area: {}".format(area))
    print("Perimeter: {}".format(perimeter))

def main():
    print ("Rectangle a:")
    a = Rectangle(5,7)
    print ("area:      {}".format(a.area()))
    print ("perimeter: {}".format(a.perimeter()))
    print ("")
    print ("Rectangle b:")
    b = Rectangle()
    b.width = 10
    b.height = 20
    print (b.getStats())

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems, such as omitting `self` when referring to instance attributes, omitting calls (`()`) when referring to functions or defining a class, naming `__init__` as `init`, and having improper formatting/indentation. The following code repairs these errors and seems to work.

```
class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self,height=2, width=2):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
    def setHeight(self, height):
        if type(height)!=int:
            self.height = 2
        else:
            self.height = height
    def setWidth(self, width):
        if type(width)!=int:
            self.width = 2
        else:
            self.width = width

    def getHeight(self):
        return self.height
    def getWidth(self):
        return self.width

    def perimeter(self):
        perimeter = ((2*self.height)+(2*self.width))
        return perimeter

    def area(self):
        return self.height * self.width

    def getStats(self):
        print("Width: {}".format(self.width))
        print("Height: {}".format(self.height))
        print("Area: {}".format(self.area()))
        print("Perimeter: {}".format(self.perimeter()))

def main():
    print ("Rectangle a:")
    a = Rectangle(5,7)
    print ("area: {}".format(a.area()))
    print ("perimeter: {}".format(a.perimeter()))
    print ()
    print ("Rectangle b:")
    b = Rectangle()
    b.width = 10
    b.height = 20
    b.getStats()

main()
```

Result:

```
Rectangle a:
area: 35
perimeter: 24

Rectangle b:
Width: 10
Height: 20
Area: 200
Perimeter: 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Any method specific to an instance of the class, should pass in self as an input. For instance:

```
def setHeight(self, height):
    if type(height)!=int:
        self.height = 2
    else:
        self.height = height
```

I believe the problem you are running into is that you are trying to access attributes of the Rectangle "b" with `b.width`. Since you did not pass in self to the methods, the height and width variables are not specific to any one instance of the Rectangle class. Furthermore, you should avoid accessing attributes directly. So instead of using `b.width=10`, use `b.setWidth(10)`